# Polymer Unminified Source Code

Tags: polymer

Where is the unminified Polymer source code?

All source files are minified at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/polymer/polymer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unminified source can be found here: https://github.com/polymer/polymer-dev